# setJavaScriptEnabled doesn't work in webview

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-studio

I have a simple layout that contains a webview.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Inside this webview i loaded some HTML dinamically on the OnCreate Method.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView displayVideo = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    displayVideo.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    String html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"/> <title></title><script src=\"http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js\"></script> <script> $(document).ready(function () {debugger$(\"#tituloPrueba\").css('color', 'red'); }); </script></head><body><h1 id=\"tituloPrueba\">Test</h1> </body></html>";
 displayVideo.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/web/", html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

*As you can see in the loaded HTML, I am calling jquery from code.jquery.com

In the document ready i am testing jquery by adding css class to

```
<h1 id=\"tituloPrueba\">Test</h1>
```

when i execute the app nothing changes, i am guessing javascript or jquery is not working.

By the way: in the method

```
 displayVideo.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/web/", html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

I have no idea what "file:///android_asset/web/"" is for , maybe the problem is there?

Comment: Do you have ` <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Yes, i have the permission.